what causes a gcloud functions deploy failure with no error message (OperationError: code=13, message=None)
deploying from a GitHub workflow with this command
          gcloud functions deploy "$FUNCTION_NAME" \
              --entry-point "entry" \
              --region northamerica-northeast1 \
              --runtime python39 \
              --set-env-vars=SENDGRID_API_KEY="$SENDGRID_API_KEY" \
              --source "my-source-folder" \
              --timeout "540s" \
              --trigger-topic "my-trigger-topic"

I get this error
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
..
For Cloud Build Logs, visit: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=northamerica-northeast1/<<snip>>
...............................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=None
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I have other another Function that deploys successfully with the same command line args.
What will fix this and|or how do I troubleshoot it?

self answer:

After googling and not finding that exact non-error message from anybody else and thinking about how old the version of Python was, I suspected that I needed a newer runtime.
By setting my cloud project (gcloud config set project my-project) and running the cloud functions deploy ... command locally on a command line, I could do some trial and error.
Trying the runtime of python312 produced a whole pile of errors. Using a runtime of python39 worked. I had heard that there were problems with 3.11 and I was happy it worked so I stayed with pyton39.
